# Why doesn't ESLint complain about implicit `any` returned from function call?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

Why doesn't ESLint complain about implicit `any` in this line:

```
// `serializedResult` is `any` and that's okey becauase `sendMessage(...)` return value 
// has `Promise<any>`. But why eslint doesn't complain?
const serializedResult = await browser.runtime.sendMessage(serializedPacket);
```

Configuration files:

```
// type declaration for function come from `index.d.ts`:
declare namespace browser.runtime
{
    ...
    function sendMessage(message: any, options?: _SendMessageOptions): Promise<any>;
    function sendMessage(extensionId: string, message: any, options?: _SendMessageOptions): Promise<any>;
    ...
}
```

```
// .eslintrc.json
{
    "env": 
    {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": 
    [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": 
    {
        "ecmaVersion": "latest",
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "ignorePatterns": 
    [
        "bin/**"
    ],
    "plugins": 
    [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": 
    {
        "prefer-rest-params": "off",
        "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "error"
    }
}
```

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions":
    {
        "target": "es2022",
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Should this work?

Comment: Its source is a [TS compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noImplicitAny), and that only prevents _inferred_ `any`s; as the type of the variable is not inferred, but sourced from `sendMessage`, there is no issue.

Comment: ESLint doesn't detect this, this should be catched by TS compiler `noImplicitAny` option , but because declaration has explicit `any`, compiler doesn't see problem.

Comment: Any proposal how to catch situations like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two tools in play here:

- ESLint (a *linter*): runs a configurable list of rules. Each lint rule checks for one particular problem and might report on instances of the problem it finds.
- TypeScript (a *language*): lets you write code in a syntax that includes all of JavaScript plus some new constructs for types. It includes a type checker that warns you if some code has mismatched types.

TypeScript's [`noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://aka.ms/tsconfig#noImplicitAny) only complains about *parameters* and *variables* whose type cannot be inferred. If something is known to be type `any` and assigned to some variable, that's a wholly separate issue. It's not an "implicit" `any`.

What you're looking for is a lint rule that can find places in code that have an `any`. There are a few lint rules in [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io) (the parser & ESLint plugin that add TypeScript support and TypeScript-specific rules to ESLint):

- [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment)
- [`plugin:@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-return)
- ...and more in [typescript-eslint.io/rules](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules)

Those rules are all lint rules that require [linting with type information](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting) because they require using TypeScript APIs to determine the types of things. In this case, they'd need to use type information to know which values are `any`.

Your ESLint config isn't enabling those rules because it's only set to extend from `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"`, which doesn't enable lint rules that require type checking. `"plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked"` does that. You can read more about the preset typescript-eslint configs on [typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/configs).

Comment: So, my configuration was wrong. Apart from missing `plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-type-checked`, I also need configure `parserOptions.project`, but I figured it by myself.

Comment: Also thanks, really splendid answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm one of the maintainers on typescript-eslint and this comes up a lot. If there's anything unclear in our docs please do let us know on github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint. :)